# Jaxb custom String adapter binds to Java type List<String>

Tags: java, jaxb2

I am using a custom String adapter to trim and remove extraneous spaces but leave the newline characters.
I created a bind file to use the new adapter

xjb:

```
<jaxb:globalBindings>
<xjc:javaType name="java.lang.String" xmlType="xsd:string" adapter="com.xsd.adapter.CleanStringAdapter"/>        
        <xjc:serializable uid="1" />
</jaxb:globalBindings>
```

xsd:

```
<xs:complexType name="BarStatus">       
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="BarType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />          
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="ShortDescription" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="LongDescription" type="xs:string" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>
```

Generated Java class attributes

```
private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(name = "BarType", required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CleanStringAdapter.class)
    protected List<String> barType;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Id", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "nonNegativeInteger")
    protected BigInteger id;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Name", required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CleanStringAdapter.class)
    protected String name;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "ShortDescription", required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CleanStringAdapter.class)
    protected String shortDescription;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "LongDescription", required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CleanStringAdapter.class)
    protected String longDescription;
```

But the attribute BarType which is of type List is also being mapped to the CleanStringAdapter causing 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String during marshaling

Is there a way to restrict the mapping only to String type and not to List?